# React component rendered twice using server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-rendering

I have an app where I configured server side rendering. Everything is working nice and my component is rendered on the server. The problem is that I get my component rendered twice on the screen. One comes from `<div id="content"><%- content %></div>`that I am using for server rendering and one comes from `<script src="http://localhost:3001/bundle.js"></script>`. I use webpack to make two bundles for my server and client. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

**views/index.ejs**

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <div id="content"><%- content %></div>
  <script src="http://localhost:3001/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist')))

app.use(serverRenderer)
app.get('*', (req: Object, res: Object) => {
  res.render('index', {content: req.body})
})
```

**serverRender**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from '../client/routes.js'

async function render (component) {
  const content = ReactDOM.renderToString(component)
  return content
}

async function getMatchParams (routes, currentUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    match({routes: routes, location: currentUrl}, (err, redirect, props) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      return resolve(props)
    })
  })
}

export default async(req, res, next) => {
  const renderProps = await getMatchParams(routes, req.url)
  if (renderProps) {
    const component = (
      <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
    )
    req.body = await render(component)
    next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have found a problem. I was referring to the bundle and server rendered string with two separate `<div>`. Inside my **app.js** I was doing this

```
render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      {routes}
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Thats why I should have been sending the string to the template like this.

```
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dist')))

app.use(serverRenderer)
app.get('*', (req: Object, res: Object) => {
  res.render('index', {app: req.body})
})
```

And finally my **views/index.js** should look like this

```
<body>
  <div id="app"><%- app %></div>
  <script src="http://localhost:3001/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that problem and found a solution.

On package.json,

```
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:*",
```

It will run webpack and node build/bundle.js.
Then 2 things happened simultaneously, `webpack build project`, `node build/bundle.js`

After webpack built project, then `node build/bundle.js` runs again since bundle.js is changed.

So there was twice calls on both server and client side. I solved this problem very easily.

First run `npm run build`, then run `node build/bunde.js` . Then it will run everything once :)